# How do I create a hash of weekdays matched with dates of objects for a calendar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a cashflow management tool as an exercise.

I've a table to display a budget for a week. It has weekdays as column headers, and Income/Expenditure Categories as headers for rows (the first ). Each row is then filled with cells from the Incomes/Expenditures for that category and for that week.

The problem is the Income/Expenditure Cells aren't mapped to their weekdays, so if a day doesn't have an income or expenditure value the layout of the row breaks - the cell values don't match the column headers for weekdays.

I have Income, Expenditure and Category models. Category's have many Expenditures and Incomes etc.

I think I need to create an @week_of_incomes_by_category object in my show controller method that takes a week of previous Incomes from Monday to Friday, and then puts the results into an array of ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday, "Thursday, "Friday"] - however I'm not sure how best to do this.

I can get a week of values using .where and .order, I don't know how to create that matched Income.date with the right day value. I'm also open to alternative solutions for my weekday calendar problem.

Thanks for the help.